# Background image CSS3 infinite loop animation

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to animate some steam which is a background image on a div to infinitely loop an animation. I've got it almost right apart from there's a jump every 5 seconds (once the animation is complete).

Here's what I've done so far:

```
div#steam { background-image: url('../images/steam.png'); background-repeat: repeat-y; background-position: left bottom; -webkit-animation: slide 5s linear infinite; }
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    from { background-position: left 0; }
    to { background-position: left 100%; }
}
```

So this repeats the background vertically which is what I want, then it animates fine and at a decent speed for it to look realistic. The only problem is the jump after the 5 second animation has finished each cycle. How can I get around this?

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/UHgF8/5/

Comment: Can you provide us a jsfiddle?

Comment: jsfiddle or the page with the code working?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UHgF8/5/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fixed by using the exact height of the image:

```
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    from { background-position: left 0; }
    to { background-position: left -1790px; }
}
```